# How can i write a program that converts a binary string to a decimal integer using recursion to do the conversion

Tags: c++, recursion

I cant seem to find any errors in my program.
I'm still quite new to c++ and wasn't able to understand most examples i found online.
This is what makes sense to me, but it's also my first attempt at recursion.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int convert(string num, double dec_num, int i)
{
    if (i == num.length())
    {
        return dec_num;
    }
    else
    {
        dec_num += (pow(2, num.length()) * num[i]);
    }
    ++i;
    convert(num, dec_num, i);
}

int main()
{
    string binary = "101";
    cout << convert(binary, 0, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It returns 14622728, Thank you in advance for any help you could offer <3

Comment: Any non-void function should `return` something. Yours ends with `convert()` call. What does it return on that branch?

Comment: Going to last part of non-void functions without executing `return` statement invokes *undefined behavior* in C++. ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.6.3 The return statement)

Comment: `convert(num, dec_num, i);` should probably be `return convert(num, dec_num, i);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int convert(string num, double dec_num, int i)
{
    if (i == num.length())
    {
        return dec_num;
    }
    else
    {
        dec_num += (pow(2, i) * (num[i]-'0')); //change here 
//        cout<<dec_num<<'\n';
    }
    ++i;
    return convert(num, dec_num, i); //change here 
}

int main()
{
    string binary = "101";
    cout << convert(binary, 0, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have corrected your code and commented the modifications.